# default bookmarks location

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

For those using torbrowser in a linux OS on a bootable iso, that's then booted from USB, with something like sardu or yumi etc. Is it possible to change the location where torbrowser bookmarks get stored? So that the bookmarks could be stored on the USB outside the iso, and automatically show in torbrowser when it's run. Rather than importing bookmarks each time, or incorporating fixed bookmarks when making the OS iso, or storing the bookmarks online. Torbrowser on another OS iso on the same USB, could then use the same bookmarks file, but I'm not sure torbrowser or any browser can change its default bookmarks location.

Answer (score 0):

Make a link file to A/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/place.sqlite and store the link to B/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/

But notice place.sqlit containing more information than bookmark.

It'd better to make a link to `/tor-browser_en-US/Tor Browser`.